# Driving an Object at Half the Speed of the main Object

Tags: animation, drivers

Hi I'm animating my Engines Rotating assemblies and I want to Drive the Cams at Half the Speed of the Crank (Example: Crank is going at 1 and the Cams are at 0.5) what is the operation to make this action happen

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe give more details, show pictures, share your file, etc?

Comment: so if the Crank does 1 RPM the Cams Sub sequentially do 0.5 RPM

Comment: for example if you give a Copy Rotation constraint to an object, you can limit the Influence to 0.5. For more complex things you also have Transformation constraint. Maybe share a very simple example with one cram and one cramp?

Comment: umm I tried  the Copy Rotation Thing and limiting to 0.5 but that only copies half the Rotation not letting it rotate continuously but at half the speed. I've got a Driver on the Crank to have it calculate RPM and when the Crank is going at an Example of 75 RPM the 2 Cams must continuously rotate at 37.5 RPM

Comment: could you edit your question, share a very simplified version of your problem, and maybe explain what is supposed to happen with some screenshots?

Comment: plus, do you need one object to control the other one, or is it just for an animation and you just need the 2 objects to rotate, one half the speed of the other?

Comment: copy rotation with influence at 0.5: https://zupimages.net/up/20/43/gzb7.gif

Comment: it didnt work with the Driver on the Crank the Cam rotated Half of the Crank and then Reset

Answer (score 3):

**Use one property to drive many**

[image]

In leiu of setting up a property for RPM of the engine, will use the current frame.  All drivers added will be a function of frame.

A simple driver to rotate one revolution per second on a file using 24 fps

```
2 * pi * frame / 24
```

A driver for half this rotational speed  would be

```
pi * frame / 24
```

To rotate in equal but opposite direction, negate the value.

Can create this  driver by typing   `#2 * pi * frame / 24`  directly into a property. The hash designates it is a driver. (turns purple) *Only need the hash first time*

Here are the six drivers I have added to create animation.

[image]

Turning off use selected in the drivers editor allows us to quickly navigate from one to another.

Instead of using frame could instead set up a custom property RPM and use that in any driver for a component driven by shaft revs.

PS. Not sure I have animated the correct items, but hopefully it shows the theory of using one property to drive many based on its value.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a transformation constraint to the crankshaft, not the camshaft, and set it to twice the angular velocity of the camshaft.

[image]